# Icon unpressable if Text outside view

Tags: css, react-native, pressable

Everything inside Pressable should be pressable and trigger goBack. This code correctly allows me to press the contents inside the Pressable to go back:

```
<View style={styles.header}>
      <Pressable
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          styles.backButtonContainer,
          {
            color: pressed ? 'rgba(0, 224, 255, 0.3)' : 'transparent',
          },
        ]}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        android_ripple={{ color: 'rgba(0, 224, 255, 0.3)', borderless: false }}
        hitSlop={{ top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 }}
      >
        <Icon name="chevron-back-outline" color="#00e0ff" size={24} />
      </Pressable>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Add Gym</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
```

In this version pressing the arrow icon doesn't trigger anything yet pressing the padding does:

```
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Pressable
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          styles.backButtonContainer,
          {
            color: pressed ? 'rgba(0, 224, 255, 0.3)' : 'transparent',
          },
        ]}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        android_ripple={{ color: 'rgba(0, 224, 255, 0.3)', borderless: false }}
        hitSlop={{ top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 }}
      >
        <Icon name="chevron-back-outline" color="#00e0ff" size={24} />
      </Pressable>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Add Gym</Text>
    </View>
```

CSS:

```
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  backButtonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding:8,
  },
```

Comment: It should work! There is a chance that items are to close to the top, under StatusBar. have you tried using **SafeAreaView** instead of View for header? Or adding some margin to header view like: _marginTop: 100_ just to test? By the way, it shouldn't affect the press results but _color: pressed..._ should be _backgroundColor: pressed..._

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `hitSlop` set for the `Pressable` component, you are able to press on it outside its render view.

There could be 2 things affecting the touch area on the icon itself:

1. There might be an overlapping view on top of the icon:

Make sure that there are no absolute views rendered on top of the button.

2. The icon itself is overlapping the `Pressable` component.

For this, try to add to the Icon `pointerEvents` prop and set it as null.

Like this:

```
        <Icon name="chevron-back-outline" color="#00e0ff" size={24} pointerEvents="none"  />
```

Not sure which `Icon` library you are using, but it should inherit `View` props, in case it doesn't, wrap the whole Icon with a `View` and set the `pointerEvents` to it instead.